# Where to check "exception" and "timing_complete" events?

Tags: google-analytics, gtag.js

I'm using gtag.js. I have no problem sending this:

```js
gtag('event', 'aaa', {
  'event_category': 'bbb',
  'event_label': error
});
```

and checking it under Realtime > Events panel on https://analytics.google.com.
But I don't know where to check after I sending:

```js
gtag('event', 'exception', {  
 'description': error,  
 'fatal': true // set to true if the error is fatal  
});
gtag('event', 'timing_complete', {  
 'name': 'load',  
 'value': Math.round(performance.now()),  
 'event_category': 'JS Dependencies'  
});
```

These two special events are documented here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/exceptions. But there's no UI to check them?

Comment: It's 2023 and Google are pushing GA4 as a replacement for UA, but there's still no way to view exceptions/errors in their UI. It's crazy.